# Is my fairy castle cactus infected with a fungus?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, fungus, cactus, rot

The cactus was a vibrant green when bought and has been slowly turning brown over time. It's only watered when the soil is dry, about 2-3 weeks apart. The soil drains quick. More or less water doesn't seem to effect things. Could this be fungus? What can I do to save my cactus?
[image: cactus]

Comment: Some more info. Its been given lots of sun initially and now gets moderate indirect sun (thought it was sunburn). It's softer but still firm to the touch.

Comment: HI Jugo, it is better to edit your question to add more information.  My first impression is that it gets too much water.

Comment: Indirect sun for a cactus is novel. Give at least morning sun. Since the soil looks wet, you won't go wrong with less water. Dry cacti do not get brown for being dry.

Comment: Umm.. I really do not have much expectation from this one..I'm sorry :(

Comment: My fairy cactus has the same spots. I used regular potting soil when I transplanted it. However, I’ll be using appropriate soil for cacti with drainage when I repot it again which will be this week. Also, I live in a humid climate so I use nemoil to treat any spots and succulent plant food for nutrients.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a rot to me. Yes, for sure it is mold. Cactuses aren't meant to be left thriving in such a rich compost based medium, they prefer sandy soils with ample drainage. They can survive with too little water but not too much. Try applying Mancozeb + Carbendazim Complex to both plant as well as soil and see if it lives.